# OptionParser, requiring subparameters

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I'm trying to figure out how to define subparameters for one of my parameters.  This is what I have that is NOT working:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |parser|
  parser.on("-r", "--require LIBRARY", "Require the LIBRARY before executing your script") do |lib|
    parser.make_switch(["-p"], '--pop THING') do |o|
         puts "You required #{o}!"
    end
 end
 parser.on("-f", '--file FILE', 'File to be processed') do |file|
    puts "This is the file: #{file}"
 end
end.parse!
```

I'd like to do:

```
 ruby myapp -r Library -p thing #<--required params
```

or

```
 ruby myapp -f
```

Comment: Make `-p` a normal parameter and then check after parsing that `-p` and `-r` were passed together or not at all.

Comment: @Max  - That might be an okay solution...as long as no other argument takes a '-p' switch.

Comment: The same principle applies. There's no rule saying you can only use optparse to handle arguments. Once it's done you can do whatever kind of post-processing you want to handle more complex cases.